# Is there a way I can make the stacking of the columns adjust according to the available space

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want to display the content such that the Col-1 appears first then Col-2, Col-3 goes to next line so on and so forth.

This is somewhat my code:

```
<Row>
                            <Col lg="6">
                                Agent Details
                            </Col>
                            <Col lg="6">
                                <div style={{
                                    // This is just to represent that the height and width wil vary - Right now hardcoding it
                                    height: '100px',
                                    width: '100px'
                                }}>
                                    Map
                                </div>
                            </Col>
                            <Col lg='6'>
                                About Section 
                                <p>
                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                                </p>
                            </Col>
                            <Col lg="6">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        Point 1
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        Point 2
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        Point 3
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        Point 4
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </Col>
                            <Col lg="6">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        Point 1
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        Point 2
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        Point 3
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        Point 4
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        Point 5
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        Point 6
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </Col>
                            <Col lg="6">
                                Thank you blah blah
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
```

This is visual representation of what I am trying to achieve.

[image: On mobile it is fine, but the same is causing ugly spaces in the large screen sizes. P.s I need the content in certain order, this is why I went for Col approach.]

Appreciate any help on this.

I tried the Rows and Column approach using bootstrap.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377343/css-only-masonry-layout